# Help showing $u \in W_0^{1,p}(I)$ if and only if $u=0$ on $\partial I$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, uniform-convergence

I am reading the proof the following statement provided in *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, by haim Brezis*:

> If $u \in W_0^{1,p}(I)$, then $u=0$ on $\partial I$

Where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval. I do not understand the proof given, which is as follows:

If $u \in W_0^{1,p}$ then there exists a sequence $(u_n) \subset C^1_c(I)$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1,p}(I)$.

Then $u_n \to u$ uniformly on $\bar{I}$ and as a consequence $u=0$ on $\partial{I}$.

I understand the first part,  $W_0^{1,p}$ is defined as the closure of $ C^1_c(I)$ in $W^{1,p}(I)$.

But how is the uniform convergence proved from the $W^{1,p}$-convergence? And why is the uniform convergence needed? Isn't it enough to have pointwise convergence? All of the functions $u_n$ are equal to zero on $\partial(I)$, so if they converge pointwise to a function $u$, then $u=0$ on $\partial(I)$, doesn't it?

As far as I know, $W^{1,p}$-convergence implies $L^p$ convergence of both $u_n$ and its derivative, but I don't know how to show uniform convergence.

Comment: You need some kind of continuity for $u \in W_{0}^{1,p}$ to make sense of pointwise values. If you were just working in $L^p$, then point values don't have mean because changing the values on any set of measure $0$ does not change the function in $L^p$. But when you have $u \in W_0^{1,p}$ equal a.e. to a continuous function, then that continuous function is unique, and point values are given meaning by that fact.

Comment: I have just realised $||u||_{\infty} \leq C ||u||_{W^{1,p}(I)}$, wich gives us uniform convergence.

Comment: @TrialAndError, I understand what you mean but I don't really get why you say it. $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ is the essential supremum, which doesn't take into consideration sets of measure 0. In fact the inequality $||u||_{\infty} \leq C ||u||_{W^{1,p}(I)}$ gives us some kind of *almost everywhere*? uniform convergence. The fact that $u_n$ are continuous means we have indeed *everywhere* uniform convergence, and also that the limit function is continuous, Right?

Comment: That's what you needed. Any time you're dealing with subspaces of $L^p$, you need more to start talking about pointwise values. Two continuous functions that are equal a.e. on an interval are the same.